# Python Pandas: How can I make labels for dropped data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used `drop_duplicates()` on original data(subset = A and B), and I made labels for the refined data.
Now I have to make labels for the original data, but It costs to much time and not that efficient.
For example,

My original dataframe is as follows:

```
A   B
1   1
1   1
2   2
2   3
5   3
6   4
5   4
5   4
```

after `drop_duplicates()`:

```
A   B
1   1
2   2
2   3
5   3
6   4
5   4
```

after labeling:

```
A   B   label
1   1   1
2   2   0
2   3   1
5   3   1
6   4   0
5   4   1
```

Following is my expected output:

```
A   B   label
1   1   1
1   1   1
2   2   0
2   3   1
5   3   1
6   4   0
5   4   1
5   4   1
```

My current code for achieving above result is as follows:

```
for i in range(origin_data):
  check = False
  j = 0
  while not check:
    if origin_data['A'].iloc[i] == dropped_data['A'].iloc[j] and origin_data['B'].iloc[i] == dropped_data['B'].iloc[j]:
      origin_data['label'].iloc[i] = dropped_data['label'].iloc[j]
      check = True
    j+=1
```

As my code takes much more time, is there any way I can perform it more efficiently ?

Comment: What is the logic for labeling?

Comment: I used neural network for labeling. The data is text data, and the length is nearly 200k,and  it needs more than 5 hours to run....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the labeled dataset with the original one:

```py
original.merge(labeled, how="left", on=["A", "B"])
```

result:

```
   A  B  label
0  1  1      1
1  1  1      1
2  1  2      0
3  1  3      0
4  1  4      1
5  1  4      1
```

Full code:

```py
import pandas as pd

original = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1},
     'B': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 4}}
)

labeled = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1},
     'B': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4},
     'label': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1}}
)

print(original.merge(labeled, how="left", on=["A", "B"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just mapping the 'B' labels to the original dataframe, you can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
origin_data.B.map(dropped_data.set_index('B').label)
```